# What happens if a passenger wants to get off the plane during a runway delay because it ruins their travel plans completely

Tags: air-travel, compensation, delays

(Tried asking this on aviation because it concerns FAA rules and was closed
https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/88512/what-happens-if-a-passenger-wants-to-get-off-the-plane-during-a-runway-delay-bec?noredirect=1#comment236667_88512)

I am taking a 3hr flight from A to B to attend a funeral in B. Take-off scheduled for 1200, landing scheduled for 1500. Funeral scheduled for 1700h. According to flightstats this flight has an on-time rate of 93%. Assume it takes 1h to travel to the funeral.

Now say there is a runway delay of 1.5hrs (so far). If we take off right now I can get to the funeral at 1730 which is no longer worth it. If the delay goes on any longer I will miss it completely. There is no longer any reason for me to travel and even though I can't get my money back (sunk cost). At this point, getting off the plane is a no-brainer for me.

I am sure flight attendants have a plan for panicking travelers but I think this is different. The airline sold me a service and then did not deliver it. In other businesses this is where I just walk away, even without any hope of a refund.

Does anyone here know about anything like this happening? Are there any FAA regulations about this? Airline regulations? Precedent?

Obviously, I would never cut it this tight in real life given how unreliable flying has become. But I am currently on a long runway delay (no funeral) so am curious.

Comment: What if the delay occurs during the flight? Will you want the plane to turn around and carry you back to A?

Comment: You open the emergency door, activate the slide (optional), jump out and eventually get arrested.  Sadly this has been done multiple times in just the last year.  Bonus is that you'll be banned from the airline and never have to worry about delays with them again.

Comment: Have you already read [the Department of Transportation's page on tarmac delays](https://www.transportation.gov/individuals/aviation-consumer-protection/tarmac-delays)?   First hit for the phrase on Google.

Comment: Out through the toilet, then start running; https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/53027/can-you-escape-an-aircraft-through-the-lavatory. Disclaimer: You'll probably fail or get shot.

Comment: @PeterM whether the slide deploys is decided by whether the door is armed, not by any choice of the opener.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I was trying to convey that some exits (such as over the wing - depending on plane type) do not have slides.  And at least one of the passengers that took that route in the last year was in a plane without such a slide.

Comment: what location ?

Comment: On the financial side of things with some airlines, you can declare a "trip in vain" and the airline will put you on the next flight back to your origin once you reach your next destination, and depending on the length of the delay, may issue some kind of compensation, either a partial (or sometimes even full) refund on the ticket or credit towards a future flight, or they may allow you to use the ticket again on a future date. Obviously more expensive tickets and high status passengers are more likely to get more generous compensation for a trip in vain.

Comment: @Crazymoomin I am surprised the airline would pay for what is effectively bad planning on the customer's part.  I gather the airline is not Ryanair lol.  As a transcon Amtrak rider I would be positively negligent not to plan for a 6 hour late arrival.  And my worst delay was indeed 6 hours.  However it was on Jetblue.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica well there are limits to what a customer can plan for in terms of contingency. Some things are just tight and there's no way around it, not without more time off work they might not be able to take, or making trips like weekend getaways unviable.

Comment: @Crazymoomin With the climate crisis and other planetary boundaries, weekend getaways by plane are *already* unviable until sustainable aviation fuels are widely used.

Comment: @gerrit That's not really relevant to the topic at hand.

Comment: @Crazymoomin That sounds like a business traveler's problem.  People like that tend to pay business traveler's prices, so I can see the airline working with them.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica it probably depends on the length of the delay, long enough and in many countries legal protections kick in.

Answer (score 52):

(From your mention of FAA I assume you are interested in the United States.  Rules in other parts of the world may be different.)

Yes, the US Transportation Department has [specific regulations for "tarmac delays" at 14 CFR 259.4](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c327ec1c760c8a98e3e37f6fb85854d1&mc=true&node=pt14.4.259&rgn=div5), as well as an [informal summary for travelers](https://www.transportation.gov/individuals/aviation-consumer-protection/tarmac-delays).

The general rule is:

> [14 CFR 259.4 (c)(1)] For all domestic flights, each covered U.S. air carrier shall provide a passenger on a flight experiencing a tarmac delay at a U.S. airport the opportunity to deplane before the tarmac delay exceeds three hours in duration, subject to the exceptions in paragraph (c)(3) of this section.

For international flights, the limit is four hours instead.  There are exceptions in case deplaning would be unsafe, or would significantly disrupt airport operations.  There is also a technicality that they only have to *begin* the process of returning to the gate before the three-hour mark, and it's okay if it takes longer before they actually get to the gate and can start deplaning.

Airlines could of course make their own policies promising to return to the gate sooner, but as far as I know, none of them have.

So in your example, you are out of luck.  If the delay has only been 1.5 hours, the airline is not yet under any obligation to take the plane back to the gate so you can get off.

(It should go without saying that you should not attempt to get off of your own accord, e.g. via emergency exits, nor to force a return to the gate by causing a disturbance, threatening violence, or anything like that.  Those are federal crimes.)

If the flight should manage to take off within a further 1.5 hours, you will just have to go along with it, even though it ends you up somewhere that you no longer want to go.

In future, plan your itinerary accordingly.

Comment: I think that quote uses an extremely weird way of saying the airlines can wait up to 3 or 4 hours before having to let you get off.

Comment: Also note there is a question around about such a situation where passengers were allowed to get off, but the airline refused to return checked luggage...

Comment: "Plan your itinerary accordingly." In other words, "Leave the day before your engagement and book an hotel room for the night", right?

Comment: @nick012000 If it is important to you that you make the appointment, yes. I would do this for a job interview, court appearance, business meeting, wedding, funeral, etc. Wouldn't you?

Comment: @nick012000: For instance.  Or, in OP's case, it seems like their main goal was to be able to stay home if it turned out they could not make it to the funeral.  So they could have booked a flight with a departure time of about 1000h.  If the delay is under 3 hours, they probably make it to the funeral on time; if the delay exceeds that, the FAA rule means they can get off the plane and stay home.

Comment: @nick012000 This is, of course, not always possible or affordable.

Comment: @YanickSalzmann There's a difference between beginning the process of getting there and actually getting there, especially if there's congestion on the taxiway and you're in the middle.

Comment: The "begin" was not really confusing to me, seems like a standard detail to be flexible enough. The weird part is that the "before" has no relation to anything. Its probably legalese but I would have found "For flights departing from an U.S airport, airlines cannot wait longer than 3 hours before beginning to move the airplane to a location where passengers can safely get off." (+ the 4 hour one) already slightly clearer.

Comment: @YanickSalzmann: The [official regulation](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?SID=c327ec1c760c8a98e3e37f6fb85854d1&mc=true&node=pt14.4.259&rgn=div5) has the language "before the tarmac delay exceeds three hours in duration".  I think they tried to simplify the language for the general public, but maybe the result wasn't ideal.

Comment: Thats actually much clearer (to me) :-)

Comment: @YanickSalzmann I guess I'm reading this differently. I interpret "shall provide ... the opportunity to deplane before the ... delay exceeds three hours in duration" as saying that one may deplane before 3 hours. Once 3 hours are up, it's no longer possible to deplane, at least not by that rule. Both you and Nate Eldredge seem to interpret what's more sensible, but it really seems to me like it's miswritten, like it should say "after" rather than "before". IOW, "shall provide the opportunity to deplane *after* 3 hours".

Comment: @JoL "shall provide" means they must do that, in order to comply with the rules. If the delay is greater than three hours and they have not provided the opportunity to deplane, then they are out of compliance. There is no further requirement for them to NOT provide the opportunity to deplane. The "at least not by that rule" part of your comment acknowledges all of this. If you wrote "shall provide the opportunity to deplane after 3 hours" why wouldn't they wait 6 hours? That's after 3 hours, right?

Comment: @Segfault Thanks, that clears things up. What an interesting way to write. It seems like it's written in the negative, but you're right that it's not.

Answer (score 31):

**It's not going to happen.**

You cannot exit the plane without it going back to the gate. It's unsafe. The crew will refuse to let you. If you continue to try they will probably restrain you and you will be in other trouble.

The plane will not return to the gate for you to disembark just because you have decided you want to. Doing so will delay the plane further, possibly much further, and inconvenience all the other hundreds of passengers on the plane.

If you attempt to exit the plane after being told not to, or otherwise disrupt the flight, you will compromising the safety of the plane. The probability is that the plane will return to the gate, where you will be arrested, as well as delaying the plane more and causing you to be very unpopular with other passengers. The punishment you receive will be significant, and part of it will probably be that you will not fly again for a long time.

For a long enough delay the plane will return to the gate to let you disembark, but I believe the norm is 3 or 4 hours.

You should be able to obtain some compensation for the delay, depending on circumstances and jurisdiction. Assuming you haven't tried to force your way off the plane.

Comment: "...Doing so will delay the plane further..." not to mention all the other planes using the airport. At a busy location, the costs associated with any delay would be very high.

Comment: @David An aircraft returning to the gate to have an unruly passenger arrested wouldn't normally delay the other aircraft at that airport, at least not by a significant amount. Possibly by a couple of minutes if they're in a position where they'll need to take the runway in order to taxi back, but otherwise generally not by much. It will, however, cause a considerable delay for _your_ flight and your fellow passengers (and crew) will not be happy. It could also end up causing your flight to get cancelled if, for example, the crew times out as a result.

Comment: What does it mean “the crew times out”?

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov If the crew times out, it means that they wouldn't be able to complete the flight before their maximum number of working hours is reached.

Comment: the OP very obviously meant going back to the gate .. not climbing out (with a rope?) and walking back over the tarmac

Answer (score 8):

I once flew London to New York; flight diverted to Boston because of bad weather and stayed on the tarmac for 3 hours; a family who asked to leave the plane at Boston were firmly told this was not allowed. Eventually the crew ran out of flying hours and all the passengers were disembarked; the family were still told they had to continue their flight for immigration reasons, but they absconded.

Comment: AIUI, any passengers should have been able to leave, once the plane was at a gate, *except* if the airport was not an international airport (i.e., no customs/immigration on-site). Which should only happen in a rare emergency situation, but every so often something like that happens and it gets tricky because the passengers have to, essentially, be quarantined in one section of the airport until they can get a replacement flight out.

Answer (score 1):

> There is no longer any reason for me to travel and even though I can't get my money back (sunk cost). At this point, getting off the plane is a no-brainer for me.

Think of air travel as a group project in school. Just because you no longer have an interest in biology (being on the plane) does not mean you get to ruin it for others.

When a plane is delayed it has to wait diligently (up to 3 hours) for the ATC to clear them for take-off. This window of opportunity is small so the plane must be ready to go at all times.

Short of a medical emergency, if you were to miraculously convince the crew to go back to the gate and the plane gets cleared for takeoff while you're deboarding then you will make a lot of silent (sometimes loud) enemies because now they have to wait for clearance again.

If the flight crew times out then they have to wait for another crew; sometimes from an incoming flight.

If people are making international connections it is imperative to at least get them one step closer to their destination. If you're in a small city and destined for a big city then think about how much more likely the other people can connect to their final destination.

---

As for compensation, read your airlines' ToS. It's usually [SOL](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shit_out_of_luck#English) for weather delay but you could request a full refund for mechanical issues.

Better yet, get travel insurance next time.

Comment: SOL = Statute of Limitations, stoppage of leave, or (edited) shit out of luck?  Please [edit] if I guessed wrongly.